# Without including #include <ctype.h>

Tags: c, header-files

I have written the below programs without including `#include <ctype.h>`. I am able to execute the program. Where are these prototypes declared? I am using `gcc`.

1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    if(isalnum(';'))
        printf("character ; is not alphanumeric");
    if(isalnum('A'))
        printf("character A is alphanumeric ");
    return 0;
}
```

2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Lower case of A is %c \n", tolower('A'));
    printf("Lower case of 9 is %c \n", tolower('9'));
    printf("Lower case of g is %c \n", tolower('g'));
    printf("ASCII value of B is %d \n", toascii('B'));
    printf("Upper case of g is %c \n", toupper('g'));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try to pass invalid arguments, compiler might output place where prototype is declared.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Which version of C?

Comment: `if(isalnum(';')) printf("is not alphanumeric");` ? Are you sure?

Answer (score 8):

1. In your code these functions are *implicitly declared*, so they are not included from any particular header. If you crank up warning level for your compiler, you will see (e.g. GCC):

   ```
   $ gcc -Wall -o a.c
   a.c: In function ‘main’:
   a.c:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘isalnum’
   ```

   If the definition of the function is not available, the compiler assumes i's a function taking any number of arguments and returning `int`. For example, the following compiles:

   ```
   main(){fgetc(1,2,3,4,5);}
   ```
2. As to where they *should* be declared, it's the `<ctype.h>` header. Of course, different C implementations may include this header in other headers, so the code may appear to work without including `<ctype.h>`, but if you want your code to compile without warnings across different C implementations, you should include this header.

Comment: yes , i am getting warnings.......  without using Wall option i am getting correct answer.....but my question is where these proto types are declared other than ctype.h

Comment: @venkat, sorry I got carried away explaining implicit declarations and forgot the original question :)

Comment: "different C implementations may include this header in other headers" - no they mayn't. Standard headers can be inter-dependent in C++, but not in C.

Comment: @Steve Jessop but can standard headers include internal headers interdependency?

Comment: @Steve Jessop PS Also, I've just looked through headers on OSX and <memory.h> includes <string.h>, or one of them isn't a standard header?

Comment: @Alex B: Well, two different standard headers could include some internal `<implementation_bits.h>`. But a standard header isn't allowed to define any non-reserved symbols other than the ones it's specified to. So for example if `<implementation_bits.h>` is where `isalnum` is defined, then `<stdio.h>` isn't allowed to include it. If it instead defines `_Isalnum`, then any standard header can include it, because that's a reserved name so the implementation can use it as it pleases.

Comment: @Steve Jessop Oh, found another one: <wctype.h> includes <ctype.h> (via <_wctype.h>), which definitely defines `isalpha` due to this transitive inclusion.

Comment: @Alex B: `<memory.h>` isn't standard. wctype is probably allowed because of "7.26 Futurelibrary directions" - several categories of names are reserved. So what I missed is that if all the names defined in `<ctype.h>` fall into those categories, then `<ctype.h>` can be included by other standard headers, or for that matter they could be defined by the implementation if you don't include any standard headers. In particular, the prefix `is` + lowercase letter is reserved, so `isalnum` is fair game.

Answer (score 2):

A function doesn't need to be declared to be used (but I'd expect modern C compiler to give a warning in such cases) if it is used with the correct argument.  It is as if the function had be declared

```
int isalnum();
```

(and not

```
int isalnum(...);
```

which isn't C -- one need at least one named paramater -- and if it was variadic functions may use a different calling convention than non variadic one).

This is possible only for function returning `int` and having parameters which are not touched by promotion (char and short are touched by promotion; functions from the standard library often are in this class for historical reason).

Comment: ah technically I think you're right, AProgrammer.. I guess the point I was trying to make is that any number of parameters can be passed to a function because the code making the function call is responsible for cleaning up the stack, not the called function. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: `int isalnum(...);` is invalid C: variadic functions need at least one named parameter

Comment: @Christophe, right.  Forgot that (it is a difference between C and C++ and I do more C++ than C -- not that variadic function without named parameter are very usefull outside template tricks).  It was mainly an addition due to an answer which has been deleted since.