# Wrong answer while Changing the upper case letters to lower case and vice versa

Tags: c, loops, if-statement

I can't identify the mistake. In place of `a`, `A` has to be printed but some other letter is printing. Same in the case of other letters. Please help to find the mistake.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char m[20];
    int i;

    printf("Enter any string:");

    gets(m);

    for(i=0;i<=strlen(m);i++)
    {
        if(m[i]>=97&&m[i]<=122)
            m[i]=m[i]-26;
        else
            m[i]=m[i]+26;
    }

    printf("%s\n",m);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider using `toupper` and `tolower` found in `<ctypes.h>`

Comment: @user3386109 may be the problem is OP's assignment, not using any prototype.

Comment: Do not use magic values! Also note that your conde has complexity `O(n**2)` (N squared), as `strlen()` is called for each iteration. Using `m[i] != '\0'`has `O(n)`.

Comment: @rakeb.void: Are there really such assignments? They are complete nonsense and counterproductively. Who makes such constraints? Can't be someone who ever worked with foreign code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value will be 32 not 26.

```
if(m[i]>=97&&m[i]<=122)
     m[i]=m[i]-32;
else
     m[i]=m[i]+32;
```

Better to use for checking `isupper` and `islower`. Then change by `tolower` and `toupper`. Then you don't have to think about ASCII value.

```
if(isupper(m[i]))
{
     m[i]=tolower(m[i]);
}
else
{
     m[i]=toupper(m[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the loop the following way

```
for(i=0; i < strlen(m); i++ )
          ^^^
```

Otherwise you overwrite the terminating zero.

And instead of magic numbers 97 and 122 it is better to use letters 'A' and 'Z'.
For example

```
  if ( m[i] >= 'A' && m[i] <= 'Z' )
```

Also it seems this statement

```
  m[i]=m[i]-26;
```

is wrong

I think you mean the following

```
  if ( m[i] >= 'A' && m[i] <= 'Z' )
      m[i] = m[i] + 'a' - 'A' ;
  else if ( m[i] >= 'a' && m[i] <= 'z' )
      m[i] = m[i] - 'a' + 'A' ;
```

Take into account that there are standard functions `isupper` and `islower` and correspondingly `toupper` and `tolower` declared in header `<ctype.h>`

Also function `gets` is not supported any more by the C Standard because it is unsafe. I advice to use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @Fiddling Bits There are many low-qualified participants that usually hurry to down-vote answers.:)

Comment: You are right @Vlad from Moscow. And this is the best ans.

Comment: Sir, I know that isupper and islower is the function of <ctype.h>. But if I don't use this header file it works. Can you please help?

Comment: @NafeeurRahman See this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645982/without-including-include-ctype-h

Comment: @Nafeeur Rahman  I think that my answer contains enough information. What is not clear?

Comment: Actually sir I had a question of my own that I asked you. #Fiddling Bits helped me.

Comment: "But if I don't use this header file it works." Could you please clarify that? As it implies, `#include <ctype.h>` does _not_ work. If it is not a matter of better payment, you should definitively check why that does not work. Declaring own prototypes cannot be the solution, as they can very well be macros in your library using a lookup-table.

Comment: Fwiw, the test-free version: `m[i] ^= tolower(m[i]) ^ toupper(m[i]);` which works because for any c, at most on of tolower(c) and toupper(c) is different from c.

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion of an uppercase letter to a lower case letter is wrong.The ascii difference is `32` and not `26`.

Also you should run your loop till `strlen(m)-1` as the characters are stored from zero index.

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(m);i++)
{
    if(m[i]>=97&&m[i]<=122)
    m[i]=m[i]-32;//changing lower case to upper requires subtraction of 32
    else
    m[i]=m[i]+32;
}
```

Comment: You should not follow OP's naive approach of using magic numbers!

Answer (score 0):

Just change 26 to 32, since between the uppercase letters and lowercase characters, you have some other ascii values like [ \ ] ^ _ ...

Here's an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for you to check for yourself

EDIT: Also, when you fix that, you might want to change your termination condition (you'll probably get an OutOfBounds Exception if you don't) to `i<strlen(m)`, as you're working with a zero-based system (i,e starts with `0` and ends with `strlen(m)-1`, vs starting with `1` and ending with `strlen(m)`).

Comment: OutOfBounds Exception? You must be thinking of a different language.

Comment: You should not strengthen OP's naive approach of using magic numbers!